# 1-norm maximization, is it possible to solve it as several LP?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, maxima-minima

I have a problem of finding the maximal value of a norm as follows:

\begin{equation}\max\,\|\boldsymbol x\|_1 \end{equation}
$$\text{subject to: } A\boldsymbol x\leq b$$

where $\boldsymbol x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^\top\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\|\boldsymbol x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$.

Is it correct that I can find the answer by taking the largest result among that of the following problems:

$$\max\,\boldsymbol \alpha \boldsymbol x$$
$$\text{subject to: } A\boldsymbol x\leq b  \text{ and }\boldsymbol \alpha \boldsymbol x \geq 0$$

where $\boldsymbol \alpha = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ is progessively taken from the finite set $S_\alpha=\{\boldsymbol \alpha\in\mathbb R^n | \;|\alpha_i|=1\}$? In other words, is it equivalent if I break the original problem into $2^n$ LP problems corresponding to the $2^n$ values of $\boldsymbol \alpha\in S_\alpha $?

Comment: I guess you mean $\alpha _i x_i \geq 0 $ in the second model. What you are asking, if I understand it correctly, is if you can brute-force all possible combinations of signs on $x$, solve the LP, and then pick the case which yields the best solution. The answer is yes, it is a (naive) way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, it's really helpful.